# Reducing the number of HTTP requests for cached resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application running in IIS 8.5 / Windows 8.1.
I enabled caching for pretty much everything.

I used YSlow plugin for Google Chrome to see the number of HTTP requests for Primed Cache.
I managed to reduce HTTP requests for javascript and css files, but don't know how to do the same for .png and .ico files.

[image]

I tried to add this section in web.config under `system.webserver`

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
  <!-- Image types -->
  <remove fileExtension=".jpg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
  <remove fileExtension=".png" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png" />
  ...
```

But that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've increased the `cacheControlMaxAge` value from `1.00:00:00` to `180.00:00:00` and that did the trick.